# Why leading zeroes changes the value

Tags: c++

Consider the following code:

```
int x = 030;
cout << x;
```

Prints 24 in Code::Blocks. Why?

Comment: I guess that's the very same reason, that makes `std::cout<< 0x030;` print 48. [You may want to read this article](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal).

Comment: Starts with 'Consider': no-effort homework tell.

Answer (score 1):

It's an oktal number literal, that's the reason.

Cite from the [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal):

> *octal-literal* is the digit zero (0) followed by zero or more octal digits (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)